# Box2D:Give different fixture properties

Tags: opengl, box2d, game-physics, fixtures

I have two different bodies in my game and I want to set different fixture properties for each of them. for `brick` I do not want it to bounce i.e `brickFixture.restitution=0.0` but it does have  that bouncy effect. Is it because we cannot give different fixtures to different bodies?

```
b2Body* brick;
b2Body* circle;
```

And I their body and fixture definitions are as follows:

for `brick`:

```
b2Body* addBrick(int x,int y,int w,int h,bool dyn=true)
{
    b2BodyDef bodydef;  
    bodydef.position.Set(x*P2M,y*P2M);   //Setting body position
    if(dyn)
    {
            bodydef.type=b2_dynamicBody;  // dynamic body means body will move

    }

    brick=world->CreateBody(&bodydef);        //Creating box2D body

    b2PolygonShape shape;            //Creating shape object
    shape.SetAsBox(P2M*w,P2M*h);

    ////////////// Adding Fixtures(mass, density etc) //////////////


    brickFixture.shape=&shape;
    brickFixture.density=1.0;

    brick->CreateFixture(&brickFixture);
    return brick;
}
```

for `circle`

```
b2Body* addCircle(int x, int y,int r, bool dyn = true)
{
    b2BodyDef bodydef;  
    bodydef.position.Set(x*P2M,y*P2M);   //Setting body position
    if(dyn)
    {
            bodydef.type=b2_dynamicBody;  // dynamic body means body will move

    }

    circle =world->CreateBody(&bodydef);        //Creating box2D body

    b2CircleShape shape; //Creating shape object
    shape.m_radius = r*P2M;
    shape.m_p.Set(0,0);



    ////////////// Adding Fixtures(mass, density etc) //////////////

   circleFixture.shape=&shape;
    circleFixture.density=1.0;
    circleFixture.restitution = 0.7;
    circle->CreateFixture(&circleFixture);
    return circle;
}
```

Comment: The bounce depends on the restitution settings of both of the fixtures involved. To get a no-bounce collision, both of the fixtures will need to be zero restitution.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that we can give different fixture to different body. If you can make body static then make it static, since by default body is dynamic nature. And you set restitution manually. may it work for you.